# Confusion on authentication function in django.contrib.auth.backends.py

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to understand how `authenticate` gets the UserModel under the hood

```
# https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py

def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
        # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
        UserModel().set_password(password)
```

The confusion I have lies in `get_module` function in `get_user_model`

```
# https://hdknr.github.io/docs/django/modules/django/contrib/auth.html#get_user_model

def get_user_model():
    "Return the User model that is active in this project"
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db.models import get_model

    try:
        app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.')
except ValueError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
    if user_model is None:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    return user_model
```

and where `get_model` is defined

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/models/

def make_alias(function_name):
    # Close function_name.
    def alias(*args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn(
            "django.db.models.%s is deprecated." % function_name,
            RemovedInDjango19Warning, stacklevel=2)
        # This raises a second warning.
        from . import loading
        return getattr(loading, function_name)(*args, **kwargs)
    alias.__name__ = function_name
    return alias

this_module = sys.modules['django.db.models']

for function_name in ('get_apps', 'get_app_path', 'get_app_paths', 'get_app',
                  'get_models', 'get_model', 'register_models'):
setattr(this_module, function_name, make_alias(function_name))
```

Since `get_module` is now alias to `alias` function

I don't get how

```
get_module(app_label, model_name)
```

gets the UserAccount module specified in `AUTH_USER_MODEL` since it is equivalent to

```
getattr(loading, `get_module`)(app_label, model_name)
```

and I can't seem to find loading function in

```
https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/models
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: You are using which version of Django?

Comment: I believe I am using 1.8

Comment: The code you have pasted for `get_user_model()` is for Django 1.5. It seems the website from where you referred has not updated its code. The code for `get_user_model()` in Django 1.8 has been updated. Check this link https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L145